# bootstrap datatoggle not working with href #home tab when using both a tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**In a tag bootstrap datatoggle and href="#home" is notwoking ....how to implement it**

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#home" class="scrollto dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Oculistica Venturino <i class="fa-caret-down"></i></a>
</li>
```

[http://responsive-ui.com/babys9/](http://responsive-ui.com/babys9/#)

Comment: Please define "_notwoking_".

Comment: edit you question and create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Code pen account? Working on this side. Try this link.

```
http://codepen.io/dfrierson2/pen/RNoWZe
```

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown trigger <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#home" class="scrollto dropdown-toggle">Oculistica Venturino</a></li>


      </ul>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this should work according to bootstrap's documentation you should use a  element or, if using a more generic element such as a , add a role="navigation".

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown trigger <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#home" class="scrollto dropdown-toggle">Oculistica Venturino</a></li>


      </ul>

    </div>
```